# access to superblock in vdi, ext2

Tags: c++, unix, struct, ext2, vdi

I am trying to access the superblock in the opening and reading in of a ext2 filesystem from a vdi file. I want to use the struct ext2_super_block that exists in the ext2.h file (see line 415 of http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext2/ext2.h). I would like to just `#include <ext2.h>` but since my current unix OS is ext3/ext4 the header file is not in my system, nor is any of the files that ext2.h needs to include.

How can I include this file do get that struct? Should I be building it (the struct to hold the superblock upon read in) on my own? If I build it on my own how will the read in differ?

Here's what I have so far for my system calls to complete this (obviously don't work at the moment):

```
fd = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    .......check for errors in open
lseek(fd, OFFSET, SEEK_SET); //to skip to superblock
read (fd, &mySB, sizeof(struct ext2_superblock));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using libext2fs rather than kernel headers. It knows all the structures, it's meant to be used in userspace, and it's portable to non-GNU non-Linux hosts.